# How to resolve "blocked script execution" of Cloudant hosted web app?

Tags: ibm-cloud

My web app, hosted on IBM Cloudant, suddenly broke. The error message in the console reports that script execution is blocked (disallowed). The reason given is that the "document's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-scripts' permission is not set." I have not consciously sandboxed my web app. So why would this happen? And more helpfully, how do I unblock script execution so my web app resumes normal function?

Comment: What do you mean by "hosted on IBM Cloudant"? Cloudant is a database. Is your app retrieving data from Cloudant?

Comment: Like CouchDB, Cloudant can serve a web page almost like a web server.
> "... entire web applications could be hosted in CouchDB, without need for an additional application server." (https://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/ddocs/index.html)
> "Because CouchDB is a web server, you can serve applications directly [to] the browser without any middle tier." (Couch apostle J. Chris Anderson, https://nolanlawson.com/2013/11/15/couchdb-doesnt-want-to-be-your-database-it-wants-to-be-your-web-site/)

Comment: Then add details, like code, about what you are doing. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Your question is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69637864/cloudant-couchapp-fails-suddenly-with-csp-sandbox-error

Comment: Thank you @toka.