# Cloudant couchapp fails suddenly with CSP sandbox error

Tags: content-security-policy, cloudant

I have a couchapp which has been hosted on Cloudant free plan for years. A few days ago it started failing: the html, css and img files load but it doesn't load any of the js. The browser console error is:

```
Blocked script execution in 'https://b482ecaa-1ac2-4933-bec9-ecade207eea0-bluemix.cloudant.com/wxd/_design/app/index.html' because the document's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-scripts' permission is not set.
```

The index.html response headers include `Content-Security-Policy: sandbox`

I have a replica of this database on my local LAN and it does not have this problem, and its response headers do not include this.

I haven't changed the couchapp or any configuration at all, so Cloudant must have changed some configuration. I notice that Cloudant was updated to 2.96 on 10/14, which coincides with the timing, but I don't see anything in the release notes which mentions sandbox or Content-Security-Policy.

The [Couchdb docs](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/3.1.2/config/misc.html#csp) mention configuration variables related to CSP, but I can't find any way to change these configuration settings in the Cloudant dashboard, nor can I find any mention of it in the Cloudant docs.

Is this a configuration error on the part of Cloudant, and if so, are they likely to reverse it? If not, is there a way to change this configuration for my site or any other workaround?

UPDATE: I had an idea that perhaps I could override this by including a `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"` tag in the document, but according to CSP documentation, `sandbox` is not allowed in a meta tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, CouchApps will no longer run on Cloudant. As explained [in this blog post](https://blog.cloudant.com/2021/10/20/CouchApps-no-longer-work.html) a new `Content-Security-Policy: sandbox` header has been added to all attachment fetches. This prevents JavaScript execution and therefore JavaSript-based CouchApps will cease to function.

The reason for the change is to mitigate this [CVE](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/cve/2021-38295.html).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I suspected something like this had happened when the Acralyzer Crash reporting system I have used for the Acra backend in my Android apps all stopped working.  I am busy moving over to a new crash reporting backend.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and for writing a blog post about the issue, albeit belatedly. According to the linked CVE, CouchDB 3.2 has a way to restore the previous behaviour. It would be nice if Cloudant could expose this configuration setting, rather than just simply breaking CouchApps.

Comment: Turns out it was much easier than I thought to move my couchapp to Github pages. Almost trivial. Just had to change the XHR query to access the full Cloudant URL. Seems to be faster and should be a lot easier to maintain.

Comment: Glad to see you moved to GH pages so easily!